# trying to encapsulate $.getJSON and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requirejs

I have two javascript files:

service.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
    return {
        get: function (url, data) {
            return $.getJSON(apiUrl + url, data);
        },
    };
});
```

and main.js

```
define(['jquery', 'Service'], function($, sv){
    self.start = function () {
        var data = { project: 'myproject' };
        return sv.get('server.php', data, function(result) {
            alert("here");
        });
    },  
});
```

When data is commented `// var data = { project: 'myproject' };`

The `alert("here");` works, when not it doesn't work.

The server always answers the same.

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

P.S if I send it this way it works (but I don't want it that way):

```
return sv.get('server.php?project=myproject', data, function(result) {
```

any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, `self` looks like it's undefined. What does the console say?

Comment: oh sorry I have a bigger code where I write:  var self = this; The self.start works, and the var data works, what doesn't work is the alert("here")

Comment: I see your `get` function accepts only two parameters, while you were tried to pass a three parameters

Comment: but the ajax call works because I see it in firebug, and it doesn't return any errors. It's just that the alert doesn't work. any ideas? :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `get` function to this:

```
get: function (url, data, success) {
  return $.getJSON(apiUrl + url, data, success);
}
```

So that the callback is passed to `$.getJSON`. You say it works when you comment out `var data = { project: 'myproject' };`. I'm guessing that when you commend it out, you also change your call to `.get` like this:

```
return sv.get('server.php', function(result) {
  alert("here");
});
```

Which makes your second argument to `.get` be the callback, which is then passed as `data` to `$.getJSON`, which is completely valid, as per the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). When you do this, then it works because you've passed the callback, whereas when you have `data` as the 2nd argument, the 3rd argument gets lost in your original code. The modification I suggest above preserves all 3 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Just update the `get` function and add a 3rd parameter for callback as follows:

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
    return {
        get: function (url, data, callback) {
            return $.getJSON(apiUrl + url, data, callback);
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you to both, this is the answer